# SVN - Continue operation after disconnection and reconnection

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to update a whole repository over an unstable network.

When the connection drops, the speed lowers to zero (obviously) but doesn't continue.

I have to cancel, run a cleanup and restart the operation manually.

Is there any configuration or different SVN client that reconnects automatically?

(Using TortoiseSVN Client and VisualSVN Server over the Internet)

Comment: You should investigate why the connection drops and fix the issue first. Don't forget to double-check that VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN are up to date.

Comment: Both are, just installed TortoiseSVN x64 in my actual machine, and the server is up to date. The connection drops not because of the SVN, but the s**tty Internet I have.